# Cypress click a link in the same table row as element

Tags: cypress

I have a table with multiple rows and columns, e.g.:

```
user1@gmail.com | sometext | link (button)
user2@gmail.com | sometext | link (button)
```

I want to find user2@gmail.com in the table and in that row I need to click the link.

I tried it this way:

```
  cy.get('table tbody > tr').contains('user2@gmail.com').each(($el, index, $list) => {

        $el.find('button');
        cy.wrap($el).click();

    });
```

The user is found in the table, that's ok, but it is trying to click that user and not the button, seems the `$el.find('button')` is ignored.

can you please help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use element `contains` => `parent` => `find` => `click`. If your selectors are correct this would do the job. Though I would use a more concrete `cy.contains('td', 'user2@gmail.com')`

```
cy.contains('user2@gmail.com')  
    .parents('tr')
    .find('button')
    .click()
```

Comment: Happy to be of help.